# NVIDIA GPU states it is in use but no 3D applications are running

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8.1, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I recently got a new Lenovo Y510p with a GeForce GT755M. However, only with Chrome running, the GPU shows activity. No 3D programs are running at this time. Can someone explain this to me?
[image: NVIDIA GPU activity indicator]

Here is what I found using Task Manager:
[image: TaskMGR-1]
[image: TaskMGR-2]
[image: TaskMGR-3]

Comment: Chrome uses also the GPU

Comment: Just closed it and restarted it. The GPU is still being used.

Comment: The GPU is not only in use if 3D applications are running. But the first step would be to open your task manager and to check what is running on your PC.

Comment: Most of the UI nowadays use hardware accelerations.

Comment: @Devid I just added what processes were running on Task Manager, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Windows itself using the GPU.
[The Desktop Window Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) is designed to use the GPU to give you all the fancy eye candy.

```
Desktop Window Manager (DWM, previously Desktop Compositing Engine or DCE)
is the window manager in Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 that 
enables the use of hardware acceleration to render the graphical user 
interface of Windows.
```